# android: Handler not working at all

Tags: java, android, handler

I am tgrying to run a handler that changes the text on a button ever second but it is not running at all, i get no error message or nothing.

here is the code

```
Button letterButton;
Handler handler;

String[] alphabet = { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J",
        "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W",
        "X", "Y", "Z" };

protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
    super.onCreate(bundle);
    setContentView(R.layout.changeletters);
    getSupportActionBar().hide();

    letterButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.letterButton);
    letterButton.setOnClickListener(this);

    handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(run, 1000);
}


Runnable run = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        int index = 0;
        letterButton.setText(alphabet[index++]);
    }
};
```

Comment: that's because your index is always 1...move your index variable out to a field...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You define `index` every time to `0` then increment it, but after call.
That's why your button always shows "A".

move `int index = 0;` onto `onCreate` before `handler = new Handler();`

```
new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask(){
    @Override
    public void run() {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                letterButton.setText(alphabet[index++]);
            };
        });
    }
}, 0, 1000);
```

Looks bit overcomplicated, but after some training it becomes easy.

Comment: you need to update button text every second? Then look at the `Timer` class: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html

Comment: im looking into it now

Comment: I am using it but i get an error, can you give me an example of ho to use it. maybe i am using it wrong, i get error saying "only the original thread that created the view hierarchy can touch its views"

Comment: @user3439273 the code I provided above will work at least 26 seconds :)

Comment: @user3439273 change to `[index++ % 26]` to avoid going out of bounds

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle bundle){

    // Your previous code...

    createRunnableWithIndex(0);

}

public void createRunnableWithIndex(final int index){

    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            letterButton.setText(alphabet[index]);
            createRunnableWithIndex((index+1) % 26);
        }

    }, 1000);

}
```

Comment: is the second createRunnable suppose to be createRunnableWithIndex instead?

Comment: Yep.  Thanks for catching that.  If you want to update that button repeatedly by using a handler then the handler's runnable will have to take steps to make that happen.

Comment: Thank you, your code works but it keeps on running over and over, another user provided me a code that i like best and stops exactly when i want it but yues with a little work this can also be used.

Comment: I didn't know if you wanted it to stop at Z or whether you wanted it to repeat, but both are easy enough to do.  The only dangerous thing is trying to walk off the end of the array.  Timers are good too, of course.

Answer (score 0):

I have some easy way to it whatever i have got from ur req it might repeat after Z so I have added some tweak in our old code

```
enter code here
Button letterButton;
 Handler handler;
int index = -1;
String[] alphabet = { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J",
    "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W",
    "X", "Y", "Z" };
 protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
 super.onCreate(bundle);
 setContentView(R.layout.changeletters);
 getSupportActionBar().hide();
 letterButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.letterButton);
 letterButton.setOnClickListener(this);
 handler = new Handler();
 handler.postDelayed(run, 1000);
 }
 Runnable run = new Runnable() {
@Override
public void run() {
    if(index<alphabet.size()){
  index+=1;
   }else{
  index=0;
     }
    letterButton.setText(alphabet[index]);
 }
 };
```